# Primefaces datatable render throws error Table 'var' and Column 'field' attributes must be non null

Tags: java, datatable, primefaces

Environment:

- Jboss7.2
- Java 11
- Primefaces 10

The bean loads itemss variable with an empty list and when tries to render throw a SEVERE Error Rendering View[/gestio/personaFormacio.xhtml]: javax.faces.FacesException: Table 'var' and Column 'field' attributes must be non null.

**personaFormacio.xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable id="lstAccions" var="item" value="#{personaFormacioBean.itemss}"
             widgetVar="lstAccions"
             resizableColumns="true" resizeMode="expand" scrollable="true"
             reflow="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginator="true" rows="15"
             emptyMessage="#{messages['noResultats']}" pageLinks="5"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters} "
             rowKey="#{item.id}" sortBy="#{item.curs.dataInici}" sortOrder="descending"
             currentPageReportTemplate="#{messages['resultats']}."
             style="font-size: 12px" rendered="#{empty personaFormacioBean.itemss}">

    <p:column headerText="#{messages['13.numOrdreCpMini']}"
              sortBy="#{item.curs.numOrdre}" styleClass="column-dataTable-c width60" style="width:90px;">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.curs.numOrdre}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{messages['especialitat']}"
              sortBy="#{item.curs.especialitat.nomCA}"
              styleClass="column-dataTable-b">
        <h:outputText
                value="#{sessionBean.localeCode eq 'ca' ? item.curs.especialitat.nomCA : item.curs.especialitat.nomES}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{messages['referencia']}"
              sortBy="#{item.curs.referenciaCurs}"
              styleClass="column-dataTable-c" style="width:110px;">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.curs.referenciaCurs}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{messages['durada']}"
        sortBy=""
        styleClass="column-dataTable-c" style="width:60px; text-align: right;">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.modul.durada}"/>
    </p:column>
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

**Server.log**

```
10:11:01,753 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-2) Error Rendering View[/gestio/personaFormacio.xhtml]: javax.faces.FacesException: Table 'var' and Column 'field' attributes must be non null.
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.component.api.UITable.createValueExprFromVarField(UITable.java:100)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.model.SortMeta.of(SortMeta.java:96)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.component.api.UITable.lambda$initSortBy$4(UITable.java:325)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.component.api.ColumnAware.forEachColumn(ColumnAware.java:77)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.component.api.ColumnAware.forEachColumn(ColumnAware.java:52)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.component.api.ColumnAware.forEachColumn(ColumnAware.java:48)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.component.api.UITable.initSortBy(UITable.java:324)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.lambda$getSortByAsMap$1(DataTable.java:1026)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.computeIfAbsent(ComponentUtils.java:512)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getSortByAsMap(DataTable.java:1026)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.isDefaultSort(DataTable.java:829)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:130)
    at deployment.app2.ear.app-back.war//org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:93)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:949)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1912)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:918)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1905)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:491)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:194)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:126)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
...
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1905)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:491)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:194)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:126)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.5.SP1-redhat-1//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
    ... 64 more
    10:11:01,799 DEBUG [es.app.module.commons.presentation.administracio.ThemeSwitcherBean] (default task-2) THEMEavalon-blue
```

**UiTable.java** (primefaces)

```
public interface UITable extends ColumnAware, MultiViewStateAware {
    ...
    static ValueExpression createValueExprFromVarField(FacesContext context, String var, String field) {
        if (LangUtils.isValueBlank(var) || LangUtils.isValueBlank(field)) {
            throw new FacesException("Table 'var' and Column 'field' attributes must be non null.");
        }

        return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
                .createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), "#{" + var + "." + field + "}", Object.class);
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was an emtpy sortBy="" within column.

```
<p:column headerText="#{messages['durada']}"
    sortBy="" <=======ERROR, just remove or fill this attribute
    styleClass="column-dataTable-c" style="width:60px; text-align: right;">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.modul.durada}"/>
</p:column>
```